# Error: Element is not visible comes up when accessing an element using Dynamic Xpath while the relative Xpath works fine

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a click on a Save button. Html of Save button:

```
<div class="button button--large ng-binding" ng-click="params.applyWrapper()">Save</div>
```

Now, when I use relative xpath to get a click it works fine. No error comes up and click on this element is successful.

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[@id='navcontainer']/ons-page[4]/div[2]/div/ng-form/fieldset/ul/li[8]/div")).click();
```

However, using dynamic xpath as given below yields an error "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible"

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//div[contains(text(),'Save')]")).click();
```

What could be the reason and how do I get a click on this element using dynamic xpath?

Comment: Use explicit wait for the button to be visible and try.  There might be the chances that  your first xpath locating the element from parent node so element get located but in your dynamic xpath , It is locating the element from that node itself So it is invisible as it may require time to get visible

Comment: Hi @NarendraRajput .. as per your suggestion I tried locating the element first and then waiting for it to be visible as given below   `var button = driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Save')]")));
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button)).click();`     The wait is infinite. Driver continues waiting for the element to be visible. Using Absolute Xpath it took no time to access the element. Something is fishy.

Comment: where are you adding the time to wait in this code?

Comment: Initial code was `var button = driver.wait(webdriver.until.elementLocated(webdriver.By.xpat‌​h("//div[contains(te‌​xt(),'Save')]")), 5000);  driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(button), 10000).click();`    This lead to timeout. Element was still not visible. I removed the time from this code to check the limit of timeout but it went on and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explanation as to why Element not visible error came up would be that previous page also has a 'Save' button and since in most implementations we do not destroy previous page and only make it hidden, webdriver was locating the Save button on previous page but could not access it as it is hidden hence the error Element is not visible.
Using the absolute xpath effectively differs the Save buttons on previous and current page whereas Dynamic xpath for both the 'Save' buttons is exactly the same. (Given that there's no attribute that makes the xpath different.)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[text()='Save']")).click();
```

Now, we need a way to make Dynamic xpath for both the 'Save' buttons different.
This can be done by using the **Xpath axes method**. In this method we identify an element that precedes or follows the element to be accessed and write an xpath with respect to this preceding/following element.

In my case the 'Save' button on current page is preceded by an input tag and the Save button on previous page is preceded by a span tag. This allows me to differentiate the xpath for both these buttons as follows:

**Xpath for Save button on Current page:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='defaults']//following::div[1]")).click();
```

**//following::div[1]** in this xpath represents the 'Save' button which is preceded by an input tag.

**Xpath for Save button on Previous page:**

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[text()='Test']//following::div[1]")).click();
```

**//following::div[1]** in this xpath represents the 'Save' button which is preceded by a span tag.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned this absolute xpath worked:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath(".//*[@id='navcontainer']/ons-page[4]/div[2]/div/ng-form/fieldset/ul/li[8]/div")).click();
```

This logical xpath should also work as well:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//div[@class='button button--large ng-binding'][text()='Save']")).click();
```

As you are facing `ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible` exception, you can add some `ExplicitWait` for the element to be visible & then click as follows:

```
 WebElement myElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 15)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='button button--large ng-binding'][text()='Save']")));
 myElement.click();
```

Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: same error "ElementNotVisibleError: element not visible".

Comment: @PawanJuyal Updated my Answer. Let me know the status. Thanks

Comment: I did use wait to check visibility of this element. Didn't work. I find Andersson's analysis on this issue a valid one. This element exists on previous page as well as on current page and driver must be interacting with the one on the page that is currently hidden. That's why i'm getting this error. Now question is how do I access this very element on current page.

Comment: @PawanJuyal I don't see you defining the `wait` programmatically correct in your previous comments. Did you give my last suggestion a try? Update me the status. Thanks

Comment: I'm using selenium with Javascript i.e webdriverjs node module. Given below is the code that I used to wait for the element to be visible.

`var myElement = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//*[text()='Save']"));
driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(myElement), 15000).click();`

This is what is got:

TimeoutError: Waiting until element is visible
Wait timed out after 15004ms